# Фантастика и фэнтези?

Tags: литература

Сходство и различие терминов? Синонимы ли ( применительно к литературе)?

Comment: Фантастика - это чаще всего научная фантастика. А фантэзи - это фактически - сказки. Ну, усложненные сказки. В целом, дихотомия такова.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не совсем. Фантастика — более общее понятие, объединяющее в себе всю литературу о вымышленных мирах, событиях: сказки, фэнтези, космическая фантастика, социальная фантастика и еще много чего.
А фэнтези — это раздел фантастики, который ближе к народному эпосу, сказкам и сагам. Там обычно присутствует средневековая атрибутика и мифы Западной Европы (впрочем, бывает и славянское фэнтези, основанное на мифологии славянских народов).